# App with playerduel functionality doesn't get push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am developing application which support playerduel framework. In which two players can play with each other. Person can send challenge to another one.
     i follow the documentation following.  https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push

I can get notification when i send it from command line (for testing) as describe in above documentation. But when i play game. Playerdual can't send notification when some one send challenge to another.

appdelegate code :-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

//Init Airship launch options
NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

// Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
// Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

// Register for notifications
[[UAPush shared]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.appStarted  = YES;
UIImage *bgImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
[PlayerDuel initializeWithGameKey:@"gamekey" andBackground:bgImage
                      andDelegate:[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] andOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"deviceToken:- %@",deviceToken);
// Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
[[UAPush shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
[PlayerDuel registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

for (id key in userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
}    

NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);

NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];



NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];

NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);



NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];

NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);
NSString *itemName = @"my app";
NSString *messageTitle = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive){
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1007);
 [self _showAlert:messageTitle withTitle:itemName];
}
else{
    UIViewController *viewController = navigationController.visibleViewController;
    //        NSLog(@"Controller Name:-  %@",viewController);
    [viewController.view reloadInputViews];
    [viewController playerDuelStartGame:nil];
}
NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];

NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used App Secrete as Urban Airship Key: . This is wrong. When i change it value as App Key . It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the push notifications work directly through Urban Airship and not through PlayerDuel, You probably didn't specify the right urban airship details in PlayerDuel's developers website. Make sure you put Urban Airship's Master Secret and not the App Secret in PlayerDuel's website.